# LESS variable overrides and import order

Tags: css, less

In our `app.less` file, we import a few variable files, and then the individual component style sheets.

#### app.less

```
@import variables.less /* Original app styles/colors */
@import corp-colors.less /* corporate color variables */
@import light-theme.less /* Theme definitions */

@import '../components/style' /* This file contains imports of every component in the app */
```

The `variables.less` file defines `@link-color`...

#### variables.less

```
@link-color: #1997CA;
```

And the `light-theme.less` redefines it by pulling in the corp color.

#### light-theme.less

```
body.light-theme {
    @link-color: @corp-blue;
}
```

#### corp-colors.less

```less
@corp-blue: #2a60c8;
```

Finally, in my component, I digest the variable for a tab bottom border.

#### x-component/style.less

```
li {
    &.is-selected {
       .tab-label {
           border-bottom: 3px solid @link-color;
       }
    }
}
```

As the `light-theme` is imported after `variables`, I'd expect to see the border color as `#2a60c8`, but am seeing the original `#1997CA` instead.
However, if I change the component style to use `@corp-blue` instead of `@link-color`, it shows correctly.

Am I overlooking something with import and override ordering?

Answer (score 0):

LESS variables work not like CSS variables, they calculate their values on the compilation stage, not in runtime. It seems like you need to change:

```
body.light-theme {
    @link-color: @corp-blue;
}
```

to:

```
@link-color: @corp-blue;
```

Comment: I can't do that, as I need to ensure that the new colors are only applied when the body has the theme class on it.

Comment: @NikZ then you could use [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties).